# Align an image using setLeft and setTop?

Tags: android

I have the following code, which aligns a "score" panel bitmap (to the very center of the view) before drawing it to the canvas:

```
    score.setLeft((view.getWidth() - score.getWidth()) / 2);
    score.setTop(view.getHeight() / 3);
    score.draw(c, layer);
```

As I had mentioned, this code aligns it to the center (horizontally and vertically). So, how might I get it to align to the center horizontally, but along the top of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick

score.setTop(0);

(replace your setTop call with this one)

Comment: Fair enough; thank you.

(By fair enough, I mean, yes, it's perfect.)